# Как конвертировать сроку в enum при выполнении скрипта SQL

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

У меня есть скрипт в папке ресурсы data.sql

```
insert into Product (id, name, type) values ('1', 'Falcon 9', 'ROCKET');
```

При запуске программы получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "task-2" org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/besto/Desktop/spacex/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into Product (id, name, type) values ('1', 'Falcon 9', 'ROCKET'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Ошибка преобразования данных при конвертации "'ROCKET' (PRODUCT: ""TYPE"" INTEGER)"
Data conversion error converting "'ROCKET' (PRODUCT: ""TYPE"" INTEGER)"; SQL statement:
insert into Product (id, name, type) values ('1', 'Falcon 9', 'ROCKET') [22018-200]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:622)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:91)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:38)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.access$100(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher$DataSourceSchemaCreatedPublisher.lambda$postProcessEntityManagerFactory$0(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Ошибка преобразования данных при конвертации "'ROCKET' (PRODUCT: ""TYPE"" INTEGER)"
Data conversion error converting "'ROCKET' (PRODUCT: ""TYPE"" INTEGER)"; SQL statement:
insert into Product (id, name, type) values ('1', 'Falcon 9', 'ROCKET') [22018-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:457)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
    at org.h2.table.Column.getDataConversionError(Column.java:409)
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:381)
    at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:845)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:187)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:151)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:198)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:228)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:601)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.h2.message.DbException: Ошибка преобразования данных при конвертации "ROCKET"
Data conversion error converting "ROCKET" [22018-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:875)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:772)
    at org.h2.value.TypeInfo.cast(TypeInfo.java:515)
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:378)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Ошибка преобразования данных при конвертации "ROCKET"
Data conversion error converting "ROCKET" [22018-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:457)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ROCKET"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertToInt(Value.java:982)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:806)
    ... 30 more
```

Вот сам класс продукт:

```
package com.example.spacex.entity;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force = true)
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final Type type;

    public static enum Type {
        ROCKET, STARSHIP, SUIT, ACCESSORIES
    }
}
```

Comment: Полное ощущение, что всё это выпендроны явы - ибо с точки зрения MySQL всё совершенно легитимно: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=423a7cc762a1316f36696be695935cd9 Кстати, а зачем `id` объявлен как String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При таком подходе элементы enum в базе будут храниться в виде целочисленного типа, и каждое число будет соответствовать порядку в котором декларированы ваши enum типы в `public static enum Type`.

Таким образом, если вам нужно вставить элемент `ROCKET`, выполняйте ваш SQL запрос в следующем виде:

```
insert into Product (id, name, type) values ('1', 'Falcon 9', '0');
```

Если вы работаете с БД через JDBC, то вам нужно будет и обработать преобразование полученного числа из столбца `type` в enum тип, когда будете доставать данные из БД.

Если вам нужно хранить строкой, тогда `private final Type type` объявите строковым типом. Но этот вариант также подразумевает маппинг полученного значения в enum тип своими силами.

Если используете Spring Data, поставьте аннотацию `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`, т.к. по умолчанию будет выбран механизм `EnumType.ORDINAL`

Comment: *При таком подходе элементы enum в базе будут храниться в виде целочисленного типа* В MySQL тип данных ENUM - это INT внутри и VARCHAR снаружи. Т.е. ENUM хранится как INT **всегда**.

Comment: @Akina тот же механизм использует `Spring Data` когда строит дефолтный DDL. От того и выходит, что в БД она будет хранить интовое значение по умолчанию. Поэтому есть различные конфигурации, и последняя, которую я добавил - она и есть.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы Hibernate хранил enum-ы как текст, а не порядковый номер, нужно использовать аннотацию @Enumerated

```java
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private final Type type;
```